# how to create a reference relationship in groovy domains?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

i just wanted to make a drop down box appear on the view page of my main domain.

I tried doing

```
static hasOne = [sex: Sex, accountType: accountType]
```

and I did this on the main domain but it would give me an error that the domains I wanted to have a reference with are not bidirectional. so i just tried to put a reference on the reference domains of my main domain which now made the reference domain like the accountType have a field of a specific.

I was wondering how can I just make it like a one way reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it a one-way reference, don't use the `hasOne` connection.

So, your class would look like this instead:

```
class MyClass {
    Sex sex
    AccountType accountType
}
```

`hasOne` and it's brethren indicate who "owns" a bi-directional relationship, so if you are only going one way, you don't need to use them.